# Proving that a relation is or is not an equivalence relation

Tags: logic, algorithms, equivalence-relations

So I have relation $R$ that is defined by $aRb$ if $ab>0, a,b \in Z-${$0$}

and I get that it's only an equivalence relation if

$aRa$

$aRb \rightarrow bRa$

$aRb, bRc \rightarrow aRc$

but I'm not sure how I can prove that it is or is not an equivalence relation. What steps are sensible to take, and how can I define the equivalent classes of the equivalence?

Comment: What have you tried? It is very easy to check the first two conditions. Here's a hint for the third one: In which cases is the product of two integers >0? Either both of them are positive or both of them are negative.

Comment: I just hadn't understood what the relation of the assignment and the rules the statement had to pass were, but Fabio Somenzi helped me understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify whether $R$ is an equivalence relation, you check each property in turn.

Let's start with the reflexive property and take $a \in \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$.  Is it true that $aa > 0$?  Of course; hence $aRa$ and $R$ is reflexive.

For symmetry, you ask, "if $ab > 0$ is it true that $ba > 0$?"  I'm sure you can answer that.

For transitivity, you ask, "if $ab > 0$ and $bc > 0$ is it true that $ac > 0$?"  This takes a moment's thought to decide.  If $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, and $b$ and $c$ have the same sign (so that their products are positive) what can we say of the signs of $a$ and $c$?

Reformulated this way, the answer should be easy to get to.

As for the equivalence classes of $R$, if you followed the argument above, you probably noticed that the sign of a nonzero integer is really all that matters in deciding whether it is related to another nonzero integer.  This means that there are very few equivalence classes for $R$.  Can you see them?

Comment: Would the equivalence classes then be "All positive integers" and "All negative integers" - if I've correctly understood of equivalence classes are applied to rules and vise versa.

Comment: You got it.  Those are the two equivalence classes.

Comment: How would one express this? I was thinking something along the lines of {$a \in N-${$0$}} and {$b \in N-${$0$}} and the same for negative integers, but I'm quite sure that this is at least lacking something

Comment: Those will work for the positive numbers.  You could also write $\{\, a \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a > 0 \,\}$ and $\{\, a \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a < 0 \,\}$, or $\{\, a \mid a \in \mathbb{N} - \{0\} \,\}$ and $\{\, a \mid -a \in \mathbb{N} - \{0\} \,\}$.  There are other ways as well.

Comment: Is it enough for me to do it solely for $a$, or is it expected to include all related variables which would be in this case, $a$ and $b$?

Comment: You are describing sets of integers.  What you call the variables, as long as you are consistent, doesn't matter.  In particular, $\{\, a \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a > 0 \,\}$ and $\{\, b \in \mathbb{Z} \mid b > 0 \,\}$ denote the same set.  You only need one of them.  Including both only cause confusion.